# How do I use ResourceCursorTreeAdapter with expanded and collapsed group views in Android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How do I use the ResourceCursorTreeAdapter with the following constructor?

```
ResourceCursorTreeAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int collapsedGroupLayout, int expandedGroupLayout, int childLayout)
```

I'm trying to use a it as follows:

```
_resultsCursorTreeAdapter = new ResourceCursorTreeAdapter(_resultsList.getContext(), _dbAdapter.getAllGroups(), 
        R.layout.timing_group_view_collapsed, R.layout.timing_group_view_expanded, R.layout.timing_result_view) {

 @Override
 protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
  // Given the group, we return a cursor for all the children within that group 
  int groupId = groupCursor.getInt(0);
  Cursor childCursor = _dbAdapter.getContractionsForGroup(groupId);
  return childCursor;
 }

 @Override
 protected void bindGroupView(View groupView, Context context, Cursor cursor,
     boolean isExpanded) {

  TimingGroupView timingGroupItem =  null;
  if(groupView instanceof LinearLayout){
   Log.i("TimingGroupView", "Has Header");
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)groupView;

   timingGroupItem = (TimingGroupView) layout.getChildAt(0);
  } else{
   Log.i("TimingGroupView", "No Header");
   timingGroupItem = (TimingGroupView) groupView;
  } 
 ...
```

If the group node is expanded, I want the group node to include the header for a table which each row is held in a child node.  timing_group_view_expanded.xml and timing_group_view_collapsed.xml are shown at the bottom of this question.  For some reason, the group_view_expanded is never used whether the group nodes are expanded or collapsed.  Am I using this wrong?  Has anyone else been able to get ResourceCursorTreeAdapter with this constructor to work?

timing_group_view_expanded.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/timing_group_view"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:background="@color/header_timing_color">

 <com.contractiontracker.TimingGroupView
  android:id="@+id/timing_group_item" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="30px" android:padding="10dp"
  android:scrollbars="vertical" 
  android:fadingEdge="vertical" 
  android:background="@color/header_timing_color"
  android:textColor="@color/text_color"/>

 <com.contractiontracker.RowLayout android:id="@+id/timing_group_view"
  android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="@color/header_color" android:textColor="@color/text_color">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/interval_header"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Interval" android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" android:gravity="center" 
   android:textColor="@color/text_color">
  </TextView>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/duration_header"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Duration" android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" android:gravity="center"
   android:textColor="@color/text_color"
   >
  </TextView>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/intensity_header"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Intensity" android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" android:gravity="center"
   android:textColor="@color/text_color"
   >
  </TextView>
</com.contractiontracker.RowLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

timing_group_view_collapsed.xml looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.contractiontracker.TimingGroupView 
  android:id="@+id/timing_group_item"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="50px" 
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
 android:textColor="@color/text_color"
 android:fadingEdge="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `ResourceCursorTreeAdapter` **only creates the correct layouts on creation** of a view. So if a group gets collapsed or expanded the `newGroupView()` is **not called again** and therefore the different group layouts passed into the constructor are not used as expected.

Same problem exists with the child layouts when using different ones for normal and last child. It happens there without even changing the data! After re-expanding a group the first one had the footer layout and vice-versa. Totally random and not based on position in the list.

As Aleksander O showed in his example, one can fix this by always call `newGroupView()` in the `getGroupView` method (and the `getChildView` respectively if different layouts are used for that).

To avoid always create new views, I tried a different approach that works for my case:

- Add different ids to the root element of the layouts used for group/child views
- Store those view-ids as int members of my Adapter:

  ```
  // Get the view ids for comparison
  View view = newGroupView(mContext, null, false, null);
  mCollapsedGroupLayoutViewId = view.getId();
  view = newGroupView(mContext, null, true, null);
  mExpandedGroupLayoutViewId = view.getId();

  view = newChildView(mContext, null, false, null);
  mChildLayoutViewId = view.getId();
  view = newChildView(mContext, null, true, null);
  mLastChildLayoutViewId = view.getId();
  ```
- Implementation of getGroupView (and analog with getChildView):

  ```
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          Cursor cursor = getGroup(groupPosition);
          if (cursor == null) {
              throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
          }

          View v;
          if (convertView == null 
            || (isExpanded && convertView.getId() == mCollapsedGroupLayoutViewId) 
            || (!isExpanded && convertView.getId() == mExpandedGroupLayoutViewId)) {
              v = newGroupView(mContext, cursor, isExpanded, parent);
          }
          else {
              v = convertView;
          }
          bindGroupView(v, mContext, cursor, isExpanded);
          return v;
  }
  ```

Comment: sunadorer and @Dandre thanks for the answer. But in my experience, even `getGroupView(...)` is _not_ called _when I tap on the group_ to expand/collapse it. Rather, it will take some scrolling until finally `getGroupView(...)` is called and updates `groupView`. Has anyone managed to **immediately** change the layout of `groupView` when it is tapped?

Comment: @hadi Sorry for my late reply. I still use the solution shown in my answer in one of my apps. It works fine to switch layout visibilities directly on the click on the group along with hiding all the child views. Maybe you could open a new question and show your code fragments and information about tested devices on which it doesn't work immediate.

Comment: Thanks your solution, +1. However, we can omit the 2nd step (store view ids as members of adapter), because we already add ids (@+id/group_collapsed, @+id/group_expanded, ...etc) in layout xml file. So, in 3rd step, in code, just comparing convertView.getId() == R.id.group_collapsed, ...etc is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my temporary solution for SimpleExpandableListAdapter:

```
public class LocalAdapter extends SimpleExpandableListAdapter {
    private List<? extends Map<String, ?>> mGroupData;
    private String[] mGroupFrom;
    private int[] mGroupTo;

    private List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> mChildData;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public LocalAdapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int groupLayout,
            String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
            List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData,
            int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        this(context, groupData, groupLayout, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childData,
                childLayout, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
    }

    public LocalAdapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int expandedGroupLayout,
            int collapsedGroupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
            List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData,
            int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        this(context, groupData, expandedGroupLayout, collapsedGroupLayout,
                groupFrom, groupTo, childData, childLayout, childLayout,
                childFrom, childTo);
    }

    public LocalAdapter(Context context,
            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int expandedGroupLayout,
            int collapsedGroupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
            List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData,
            int childLayout, int lastChildLayout, String[] childFrom,
            int[] childTo) {

        super(context, groupData, expandedGroupLayout,
                collapsedGroupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childData,
                childLayout, lastChildLayout, childFrom, childTo);

        mGroupData = groupData;
        mGroupFrom = groupFrom;
        mGroupTo = groupTo;
        mChildData = childData;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }        

    private void bindView(View view, Map<String, ?> data, String[] from, int[] to) {
        int len = to.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TextView v = (TextView)view.findViewById(to[i]);
            if (v != null) {
                v.setText((String)data.get(from[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = newGroupView(isExpanded, parent);
        bindView(v, mGroupData.get(groupPosition), mGroupFrom, mGroupTo);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to check for `convertview == null` or else every time new groupview will be created and recycling of list item concept will not work here causing lack of performance in scroll etc.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it explained how it's solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution with good recycling.

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Cursor cursor = getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (cursor == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
    }

    View view;
    if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() != isExpanded) {
        view = newGroupView(mActivity, cursor, isExpanded, parent);
        view.setTag(isExpanded);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    bindGroupView(view, mActivity, cursor, isExpanded);
    return view;
}
```